# MySQL Syntax Error 1064 in Insert Query

Tags: c#, mysql

Please, help me with resolving the syntax error issue

Here is the query that's causing the error.

```
INSERT INTO Task (taskNumber, idTickets, idCustomer, Topic, idUser, idUrgency, Comment, )
VALUES ('3', '4', '3', 'A and N', '1', '9', 'Please, get coffee');
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the comma for here `Comment,` <--

Comment: Also confirm that all Ids are string data type

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Task (taskNumber, idTickets, idCustomer, Topic, idUser, idUrgency, Comment, )
VALUES ('3', '4', '3', 'A and N', '1', '9', 'Please, get coffee');

After "Comment," don't need a "," or lack a tuple.